# How to call a custom system call from C in Linux

Tags: android, linux, java-native-interface, system

I have implemented a custom system call `sys_mycall` for ARM architecture. After building and downloading on the phone the log is showing that `sys_mycall` is running.

My doubt is:

1. how do I call this system call from a C file.
2. can I somehow call this system call from java (using JNI or something). Just some hint on how to implement this on Android is required.

Comment: Are you sure you need your own syscall? Generally this is a bad idea! Can't you just make a device driver..???

Comment: Actually I am trying to understand how the whole application flow works. From bottom (Linux Kernel) to top (Application Layer).

Comment: Read http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/ it is x86 specific, but you can and should transpose it to ARM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) look at `man 2 syscall` for `int syscall(int number, ...)` with it you should be able call your sys call and pass the parameters you need/want.

2) Yes, use JNI for this. Create a JNI function to call your C code and from there just make the syscall.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Android NDK

[here](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html) is an example to call C code from Android application.